# Not able to store integer data using ParquetStorer

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hcatalog, parquet

I am facing very weird issue. I have multiple column data processing using Pig. Pig uses HCatalogLoader to load data in pig script. The columns contain multiple integer data, string data and also double data. One of the column (say C1) which is of type integer fails to store using ParquetStorer. Other integer columns has no problem, only C1 column storage fails.

Below is the error:

```
Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1413268228935_0073_m_000002_0 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1413268228935_0073_m_000001_0 Info:Error: parquet.io.ParquetEncodingException: can not write value at 2 in tuple (,2003-11-22,840,00007,ABC,DEF,FFGG,10,0.0,0,0.0,11.11,0,7.122112,0.0,0,0.0) from type 'C1: int' to type 'optional int32 C1'
        at parquet.pig.TupleWriteSupport.writeValue(TupleWriteSupport.java:199)
        at parquet.pig.TupleWriteSupport.writeTuple(TupleWriteSupport.java:151)
        at parquet.pig.TupleWriteSupport.write(TupleWriteSupport.java:90)
        at parquet.pig.TupleWriteSupport.write(TupleWriteSupport.java:46)
        at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:111)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:78)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:35)
        at parquet.pig.ParquetStorer.putNext(ParquetStorer.java:121)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:139)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map.collect(PigMapOnly.java:48)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:284)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:277)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at parquet.pig.TupleWriteSupport.writeValue(TupleWriteSupport.java:178)
        ... 24 more
```

I have describe the alias which stores the data using ParquetStorer, the column C1 is of type int. Still the ParquetStorer complains the data is of type string and fails to type cast it to Number.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for this.Please share

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, my workaround is just to cast the field to chararray, and then I was able to save the output in parquet format.

Here is the source code for the function btw, 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.twitter/parquet-pig/1.2.0/parquet/pig/TupleWriteSupport.java

it seems fine to me but sounds like this could be a bug in this case:

```
case INT32:
      recordConsumer.addInteger(((Number)t.get(i)).intValue());
      break;
```

The t.get(i) returns a String and hence the

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at parquet.pig.TupleWriteSupport.writeValue(TupleWriteSupport.java:178)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: I understand this is not exactly the solution you might be looking for, but do you think you can get away with using charray to store the int value for now?

Comment: Thanks Liang for your reply! I tried to type cast it to chararray. It still gives the same error. Also, our use case will be void if store the column as chararray. Its required to store in integer format.

Comment: No problem, I am sorry that this workaround does not work for your case, let's hope someone who has more experience with the lib can shed some light on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere, so I will post what worked for me: You have to specify the schema in the LOAD statement. I was previously only setting the schema in a FOREACH/GENERATE block, but I was getting the "cannot be cast to java.lang.Number" exception. When I specified the schema in the LOAD statement then it would create the parquet file without error.

```
SET parquet.compression snappy;

REGISTER file://.../parquet-pig-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.16.2.jar;

A = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage('|') AS (aaa:long, bbb:chararray,
  ccc:chararray, ddd:chararray, eee:chararray, fff:chararray,
  ggg:long, hhh:chararray, iii:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE
  ...;

STORE B INTO '$output_dir' USING parquet.pig.ParquetStorer;
```

Of course, there are still some unanswered questions.

Comment: please show the actual statement

Comment: I added some more info, Joe.